# Performance difference between two identical MYSQL tables

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, innodb

I have duplicated a table (InnoDB) from my database to another database including all content and indexes. Both databases have been optimized, so fragmentation is not the issue. All is located on the same VPS.

I noticed a performance difference (10-20%) between the two which I want to solve.

**database1.table (Using index condition; Using where)**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT price_range FROM database1.table WHERE category = 'seating' AND visibility = 'show' GROUP BY price_range ORDER BY price_range ASC   

[id] => 1 [select_type] => SIMPLE [table] => items [type] => ref [possible_keys] => visibility_producer,price_range_visibility,category_visibility,visibility_category_price_range [key] => visibility_category_price_range [key_len] => 228 [ref] => const,const [rows] => 10106 [Extra] => Using index condition; Using where
```

**database2.table (Using where; Using index)**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT price_range FROM database2.table WHERE category = 'seating' AND visibility = 'show' GROUP BY price_range ORDER BY price_range ASC    

[id] => 1 [select_type] => SIMPLE [table] => items [type] => ref [possible_keys] => visibility_producer,price_range_visibility,category_visibility,visibility_category_price_range [key] => visibility_category_price_range [key_len] => 228 [ref] => const,const [rows] => 10106 [Extra] => Using where; Using index
```

I'm thinking the performance difference is because database1.table is using index condition while database2.table is using index. Same query, Same indexes, Same server.

How is this possible? Any tips on where to look?

Comment: I'd double-check that the tables are in fact identical with `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`. Also run `ANALYZE TABLE <tablename>` for both to make sure index statistics are up to date.

Comment: The queries are nonsensical, so I'm not sure what you want us to do :-(

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the suggestions, found two Foreign Key Constraints that were not copied. Added them to the second table and performance is now identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, verify!

The tables are not in fact identical. This is shown when examining the tables with:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>
```

In this case, examination found that two foreign key constraints were not copied when the table was duplicated.

Any foreign key requires an index, so it may build one implicitly if no existing index is used. Without the foreign key definitions, there were index differences between the two tables in this case.

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for posting your comment as an answer. I spoke too fast, after adding the foreign key constraints they were performing the same for a brief moment. Now the performance difference is back. SHOW CREATE TABLE and ANALYZE TABLE show identical results.

Comment: Is the data in the two tables also identical? The optimization plan depends in part on the data, and distribution of values.

Comment: Well I'm afraid I don't have any more ideas. There must be something different between the tables, either data or metadata. I have never seen MySQL use different optimization plans if everything is the same.

Comment: Does this measure the overhead of FKs?

Comment: @RickJames, Pieter says he now has identical FK's in the two tables.

Comment: @BillKarwin - The 10-20% diff _before_ fixing the FKs.  (Yeah, he did not say which was faster.  Yeah, there were `EXPLAIN` diffs.)